# Replace string or explode() function

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

I have a link in format like

```
http://example.com/a/b.swf
```

I want to to convert it to

```
http://cache.example.com/a/b.swf
```

How can I do it?

I tried it with PHP's `explode()` function, but when I explode some part of string, then I add it to itself it does not work.

Comment: Please show the code that you already have.

Comment: Don't `explode()` urls, rather use function [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = 'http://example.com/a/b.swf';
$str = str_replace('http://', 'http://cache.', $str);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$new_string = str_replace('http://example.com/', 'http://cache.example.com/', $orig_string);
```

?

Comment: but values comes from a variable dynamically?

Comment: $new_string = str_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $orig_string); if $map=array('http://example.com/'=>'http://cache.example.com/',...);

Comment: When you replace the complete string with http... then its equal if there paramters.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be more "professional", then use a special function http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php to parse URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php): `str_replace ($search , $replace , $subject [, int &$count ])`

```
$str = 'http://example.com/a/b.swf';
$substr = 'http://';
$attachment = 'cache.';

$newstring = str_replace($substr, $substr.$attachment, $str);
```